# How do I call Graphics Method inside KeyListener?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, keylistener

Ahead of time, I would like to say there have been many posts similar to this, however, none of them apply to me or none of them actually have any answer at all, and are outdated, meaning there could be new java features that could help me solve my problem.

Anyway, I wanted to make a game where there is tennis rackets. Of course, they would have to rotate. In order to rotate, I must call my Graphics2D method inside my KeyListener. How would I do this WITHOUT adding a new Graphics2D variable inside my key listener method?

**Here is all the methods I have that involve accomplishing this goal:**

```
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.drawImage(getPaddleImg(), x, y, null);
        }

        public static Image getPaddleImg() {
            ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Elliot/Desktop/Eclipse Game Tennis/paddle.png");
            return ic.getImage();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W){
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(5));
            } else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-5));
            }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W){
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(0));
            } else if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(0));
            }
        }
```

I know, this code would give me an error because of the `g2d` inside of the `KeyPressed()` and `KeyReleased()` method. How would I call the `g2d` inside these two methods? Or how would I do the same thing inside the `draw()` method?

Answer (score 2):

The wrong way: You can use `Component.getGraphics()` to get the graphics object.

The right way: All painting should be done inside the `paint(Component)` method. This is because a user could resize/open/close the window at any time. In your `KeyListener` (also research keybindings) you should update a setting on how the player/ racket should be drawn, and then call `repaint()`

Comment: I know that, but how do I access the `g2d` variable? I appreciate your help with that, but that won't help solve me getting the variable in my method, unless I use the "wrong" way

Comment: All (in my experience) Graphics objects can be cast to Graphics2D

Comment: do you mean `(Graphics2D) g` where `g` is a `Graphics` variable?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: I actually have used that in my code before, but how does that help when I already have a `Graphics2D` variable

Comment: What I want to know is how to get `g2d` in my `KeyPressed()` method

Comment: You can use KeyEvent.getComponent() to get the component. Then review my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK! I actually figured it out by myself! What I did is called the `g2d.rotate(.....)` inside my `draw()` method. What I did is created variables that check for rotation, and set them true or false inside of my `KeyPressed()` method. Here is the code I used inside the `draw()` method:

```
 if(isRotatingPositive == true) {
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(speed));
 } else if(isRotatingNegative == true) {
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-speed));
 }
```